# Retrieve a TextView Value inside a Adapter Class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a add and a sub button in my activity, which will increase and decrease the count when the button is pressed. How to get the current value of my textview inside the Adapter class.

```
inner class MoviesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

            val addtocount: TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieCount)

            val testcount:String=addtocount.toString()
}

    public  fun add(view:View)
    {
        movieCount.setText(""+id)
        movieCount.setText("" + ++id)
        println("Final Count is $id")

    }
    fun sub(view: View)
    {
        if (id>0) {
            movieCount.setText("" + --id)
        }
        else
        {
            id=0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the textview's id is  `movieCount` and this is what you need inside the adapter.  
In your activity create this method:

```
fun getCount(): String {
    return movieCount.text.toString()
}
```

Change the adapter's header like:

```
inner class MoviesAdapter(context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>()
```

and right below it add this line:

```
val activity: MainActivity = context as MainActivity
```

change `MainActivity` to your activity's class name.  
Now whenever you want `movieCount`'s text inside the adapter, just call:

```
activity.getCount()
```

You must change the instantiation of the adapter in your activity class because now you have to pass the context of the activity, so do something like:

```
recyclerview.adapter = MoviesAdapter(this)
```

Comment: Fantastic :) This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define all your adapter views in the viewHolder class:

```
class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val addtocount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieCount)
}
```

And do your logic in the adapter in `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
class MoviesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // here you can access to holder and all it views
        val testcount: String = holder.addtocount.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: App crashed after the above change.          override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindModel(movies[position])
            val moviecount: String = holder.movieCount.toString()
        }    inner class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val movieCount:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieCount) }   fun bindModel(movie: Movie) {
                           movieCount.text= movie.count.toString() }

Comment: Did you implement `onCreateViewHolder` method?

Comment: override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
            return MovieViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_menu_layout, parent, false))
        }

Comment: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Comment: Maybe your `movies[position]` are null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182760/discussion-between-p-alexey-and-josh).

Comment: Try holder.addtocount.text.toString()